# when i try to install discord.py it gives me error

Tags: python, pip, discord

as title says when i try to install discord.py it gives me error no matter which version i use also my os is Ubuntu 19

```
viktor@viktor-X541NC:~$ pip install discord.py==0.16.12
Collecting discord.py==0.16.12
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/3c/2a97b47fd8839f8863241857bbd6a3998d1de1662b788c8d9322e5a40901/discord.py-0.16.12.tar.gz
Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0 (from discord.py==0.16.12)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/5a/7b81ea8729d41f44c6fe6a116e466c8fb884950a0061aa3768dbd6bee2f8/aiohttp-1.0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-asBsLL/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
    RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-asBsLL/aiohttp/
```

Comment: do you have Python 3.4.2 or newer ? Maybe you install it for Python 2.  Check `python -V` and `pip -V`. You can also try to use `pip3` instead of `pip`. Maybe you have also `pip3.5`, `pip3.6`, `pip3.7` to install for different versions of Python 3.x

Comment: If you installed `pip` with `sudo apt install python-pip`, it installed the Python 2 version. In that case you should do `sudo apt install python3-pip` and use `pip3` like furas mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but line 10 reads `raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")`

What does this mean?

You don't have python installed, or, if it is installed, the version is not 3.4.2+.